# MYSQL How to determine status of the parent_record if multiple rows are present

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql DB and I need to get the output to the front end [Kind of roll up]. Instead of having logic to iterate in Java code, I would like to get as a custom column from the query output.

Custom Rule: If a team has 1 or more records as 'In Progress' in the last column, then the result set should give 'In Progress' as this team.

```
Table: Team_Counselling
 ------------------------------------------
 Team   | Player_name   |   Counselling_Status
 ------------------------------------------
Ginger  |    Alpha      |       Completed
Ginger  |    Beta       |       In Progress
Ginger  |    Gamma      |       In Progress
Lemon   |    Heth       |       Completed
Lemon   |    Kaph       |       Completed
Lemon   |    Lambda     |       Completed
Cardamon|    Omega      |       In Progress
Cardamon|    Sigma      |       In Progress
Cardamon|    Theta      |       In Progress
----------------------------------------------
```

Desired output (as in Query result)

```
 ------------------------------
 Team   | counsellingTeamStatus
 ------------------------------
Ginger  | In Progress
Lemon   | Completed
Cardamon| In Progress
```

I tried with following query, which doesn't help out.

```
    SELECT Team, 
      IF(Counselling_Status='In Progress', 'In Progress', 'Completed') as counsellingTeamStatus
    FROM team_counselling
    GROUP BY Team
```

Kindly help me out.

**EDIT**: The Following query gave me intended output. However, if better solution is available, it would be useful.

```
SELECT Team
     , IF  ( INSTR ( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Counselling_Status)) , 'In Progress'), 'In Progress', 'Completed') as counsellingTeamStatus  
  from team_counselling
group by Team;
```

Comment: Rollup is a Javascript module bundling tool, it has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the response. However, I was referring to Group_modifiers in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html which has rollup

Comment: Alright then, wasn't aware that MySQL also has a rollup

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you want a straight forward query. If the only possible and occuring values for the `Counselling_Status` column are the two mentioned, then the following query should suffice:

```
SELECT Team, Counselling_Status AS counsellingTeamStatus
FROM Team_Counselling
WHERE Counselling_Status IN ('In Progress','Completed')
GROUP BY Team;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work as Ginger team has one 'In Progress', however the query returns us 'Completed' for Ginger

Comment: @SrinivasLakshman sorry, i misinterpreted the question. I have made an edit to my answer.

Comment: Well, this too wouldn't work ! :( [as Ginger is still showing 'Completed']

Comment: 1 second please, testing.

Comment: I have updated a draft solution - if you wanna take a look.

Comment: I cannot think of another way, you should post your working solution and accept it as the answer as this is a unique situation others may be able to benefit from.